# Can someone point out what is wrong with this form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I am putting together a contact form for the first time. When I hit my submit button my website doesn't display my PHP page. My "needs validation" boxes also do not show up. I have pulled from examples from W3 schools website and the form works fine there but not when I do it. I have tried adding and removing random lines from Bootstrap's website and also W3 schools. Since this is my first time I don't know what to look for when there is something wrong.

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Right column -->
  <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5">

    <form action="/action_page.php" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" id="contact-name" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Loooks good!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out your name.</div>
              <label for="contact-name" class="">Your Name</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" id="contact-email" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out your email.</div>
              <label for="contact-email" class="">Your Email</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" id="contact-Subject" class="form-control">
              <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this area.</div>
              <label for="contact-Subject" class="">Subject</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form">
              <textarea id="contact-message" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this area.</div>
              <label for="contact-message">Your Message</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Send Button -->
      <div class="text-center text-md-left">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Send</a>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>

  <!-- Grid column -->

  </div>
  <!-- Grid row -->

  </section>
  <!-- Section: Contact v.2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">


    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->


  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.6.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-BmM0/BQlqh02wuK5Gz9yrbe7VyIVwOzD1o40yi1IsTjriX/NGF37NyXHfmFzIlMmoSIBXgqDiG1VNU6kB5dBbA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-XKa9Hemdy1Ui3KSGgJdgMyYlUg1gM+QhL6cnlyTe2qzMCYm4nAZ1PsVerQzTTXzonUR+dmswHqgJPuwCq1MaAg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've removed some sections to protect the identity of the project I am working on.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I would suggest you to start from a simple one input form. And see if when submitted the php page is loaded. Once you are sure that the data is being sent then you can try validation.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, after some finer reading I have figured it out. I had the wrong type of code for my "Submit" button. It needed to be the input type html not the "a class" button.